# How to disable stack traces in AVA and show my own error messages on error

Tags: javascript, ava

I use ava to test my Scheme interpreter in JavaScript, and I don't want to have stack traces on each failed assertion, I would like to have maybe custom reporter that will show which test failed and why and not show error that point usually to same line in evaluator.

I can easily wrote function that will display failed tests (I can write a macro that will show what expression was tested) but I can't get rid of quite big stack trace of JavaScript code that is not relevant. I would like to have stack trace only if my JavaScript code throw exception.

I'm not sure but I think that t.is throw exception when it failed. I want to tell my tests that they are failing but don't throw any exception, unless I can have a hook that will show Scheme stack trace and not JavaScript one.

[image]

Here I have message that show what assertion failed `(string<? "123" "123")` that should return #t according to spec. And the highlighted code is just  function call. Almost everything is function (like `(string? "foo")`)

I use Ava so I don't need to write my own framework, that would take weeks to write. Also Ava have code coverage and my project is JavaScript even that my tests are in Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You've highlighted what is supposed to be the source of the test failure, not an overly long stack trace. If you have a small reproduction if this it'd be good if you could open a GitHub issue. Whilst we wouldn't want a setting to disable the display of the failure, we shouldn't be displaying nonsense either.

Comment: This is special case because part of the code I'm testing is not JavaScript. It would be nice if there is a hook that you can intercept and show your own stack trace, in this can I would like see my Scheme Stack Trace, unless it was exception in my code. The stack is quite big. It would be hard to reproduce because as I've said it's special case when I'm testing different language, but I can share link to my repo but all unit tests are written in Scheme (lisp).

Comment: I've created an issue https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/2465